# Can't read from pack stream (CorruptPackFileException) | While building Unreal Engine using the start.bat on Windows 10

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-development-kit

I downloaded the latest Unreal Engine repo from github and opened the setup.bat file as per the instruction on the Official Page. The command-line opened-up and started downloading dependencies and everything looked fine until it reached 30% progress, after which it threw an error:

**Checking dependencies...
Updating dependencies: 30% (12936/41030), 1702.0/9123.9 MiB | 5.04 MiB/s...
Failed to download 'http://cdn.unrealengine.com/dependencies/3215544-fbbce13ceb6f4aaea59e20af2d659d08/36799aacce147eba397f6eacc7a0f6c9dac946d8': Can't read from pack stream (CorruptPackFileException)**

Initially I thought that it was a connection issue even though I was on a 40-Mbps connection. But it seemed to get stuck on 30% with the same error everytime. So, I started searching for solutions on the internet but could not find any, except for the clue that it was possibly a connection issue.

Furthermore I also tried to clone the repo again and again with the same result (stuck on 30%)!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Solution:

1. Goto

   ***`dir-containing-the-repo`* `\ UnrealEngine \ Engine \ Build`**
2. Open the file (which should be in the Build folder) with your favourite editor (i.e. VS Code, Notepad):

   **`Commit.gitdeps.xml`**
3. Search for this text:

   **`BaseUrl="http://cdn.unrealengine.com/dependencies"`**
4. Just replace the **http://** with **https://** and leave the rest as it is:
   Your BaseUrl should now be: 
   **`BaseUrl="https://cdn.unrealengine.com/dependencies"`**
5. Save the file.
6. Run `Setup.bat` from the folder: ***`dir-containing-the-repo`* `\ UnrealEngine`**

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me as well, but it turns out I ran out of disk space on my Linux machine in AWS. I was using 8GB.

Having a bigger volume (200GB) fixed the error for me on the next run